# Web Speech API - recognition listener length - default timeout?

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, webspeech-api

I'm trying to use WebSpeech API for 30 minutes videocalls transcript.

From what I observe, speech recognition works for more or less 2 minutes, after which it dispatches "no-speech" and end event. I've read both W3C Group Spec and mdn article and there's nothing about default timeout of the recognition timespan or any way to configure it.

Since I end and start recognition on microphone mute, I cannot use some funny fixes like:

```js
recognition.onend = () => {
  recognition.start()
};
```

as it'd automatically restart recognition on the microphone mute.